# Is it possible to build lttng-probe-... module outside of lttng-modules tree?

Tags: makefile, lttng

I would like to have all source files in one place, so my goal is building lttng-probe-xxx module outside of lttng-modules directory. I've created simple Makefile but durring compilation and next 
at when I try to loading modules I got message that "lttng_probe_register" and "lttng_probe_unregister" are undefined (the same durring compilation).

Makefile:

```
INCLUDES = -I. -I$(LTTNGDIR)/probes -I$(ROOTPWD)/include -I$(KERNELDIR)/include
KBUILD_CFLAGS += -g $(INCLUDES)

all: kernel_modules
obj-m   += lttng-probe-hello.o
PWD     := $(shell pwd)

kernel_modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules`
```

KERNELDIR is exported variable where is src of Linux kernel.

LTTNGDIR is exported variable where is src of lttng-modules.

Is it possible to link these two from lttng-probes.c to my lttng-probe-hello.ko?

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(lttng_probe_register);
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(lttng_probe_unregister);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Makefile didn't see Module.symvers from lttng-modules but only from Linux kernel. For fix it I used KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS.

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS += "$(LTTNGDIR)/Module.symvers"
```